# Why some locales are not working even if available?

Tags: java, scala, locale

I'm facing a strange situation: when I try to localize a date some languages are working, some other languages are not, even if all of them are displayed when I use `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` to get the list of all available locales. For example:

```
import java.time.Month
import java.time.format.TextStyle
import java.util.Locale

println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("it")));
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("en"))); // doesn't work
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("fr"))); // doesn't work
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("es"))); // doesn't work
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("fi")));
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("de"))); // doesn't work

Locale.getAvailableLocales().foreach(println)
```

I see the same strange behaviour if I try to reproduce on Scastie playground
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/llVhFYjQSu27UMauYw2UDA

I know that the localization depends on the locales available on the JRE, my app is currently running in a Docker container where I inserted such locales.

Comment: I have noticed an interesting thing: all the langauges you said that fail are used in multiple countries. Could the problem be connected to that?

Comment: That is a good point. I'm not sure if it is a coincidence. If I try these locales they all print 3 which suggests the month number is a (bad) fallback return value
  `Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("en_GB"))`
  `Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("fr_CA"))`
  `Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, new Locale("all the countries please"))`

Comment: Try `new Language("en", "GB")`. Maybe as you said the availableLocale displays "en" but it is not the same intance as enGB or enUS

Comment: I'm not sure where `Language` is defined. These don't work either unless you switch to TexttStyle.FULL:
`Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.UK)`
`Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.FRANCE))`
`Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.FRENCH))`

Comment: oh sorry, I meant new Locale

Comment: The difference between the 'standard' and 'stand-alone' forms is trickier to describe as there is no difference in English. However, in other languages, there is a difference in the word used when the text is used alone, as opposed to in a complete date. For example, the word used for a month when used alone in a date picker is different to the word used for month in association with a day and year in a date.

[docs]( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html)
In my opinion, the standard date should be the default value, not the number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219882/discussion-between-hawk-and-stefan).

Answer (score 3):

JDK 8 is weird http://tpcg.io/kMvv4qd7

But in JDK 11 it works https://repl.it/repls/CriminalChillyHashmap

Comment: seems like in Java 8 somebody thought it's a good idea to return ints sometimes from a function called `getDisplayName`. surprise!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just the months in different languages you can try:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols

val frenchMonths: Array[String] = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH).getMonths
val april = frenchMonths(3)
```

As for the strange behavior, I am pretty sure it is because that text style is not supported for some locales. For example:

```
// works with TextSyle.FULL
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("fr"))); 
// avoids creating a new locale    
println(Month.of(3).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.forLanguageTag("es")))
```